# Match exact string in an array in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I want to match an exact string in Perl present between two escape characters in a file.

I have tried the below codes, but they don't work when escape characters are present before and after the pattern to be matched.

NOTE : `@ary` contains contents of a `.txt` file given as an argument to the script.

```
if (grep -w (/$str/), @ary) {

   # do something

}
```

Note `grep(/^$str/), @ary` doesn't work either.

The content present inside `@ary` is in the below format:

```
/abc/pqr/pattern/xyz…
```

I want to check if pattern exists in `@ary`. The pattern should be an exact match.

Comment: try `if (grep m{/\Q$str\E/},  @ary ) {  ... }` . This will search `@ary` for the pattern `/$str/` where `$str` is a perl variable which is to be interpolated into the regex. Note: `grep -w` is not valid Perl.

Comment: The expression `if (grep -w (/$str/), @ary) { do_something() }` is actually valid Perl. It's an extremely silly expression which does nothing like the stated intention, but it is valid Perl! It won't even trigger a warning if $str and @ary are declared.

Comment: @TFBW Interesting. So it checks if the file "0" or "1" (if the the regexp matches `$_` it checks for the file "1", if not, it checks the file "0") is writeable. So most likely there will be no files "0" or "1" in the current directory and the `if` will not execute :) .. or maybe not "0", but the empty string or `undef` (which are not valid filenames?? ) hmm

Comment: What do you mean by "*escape characters in a file*"? Files don't have escape characters. Also, please provide sample data for your variables.

Comment: my @ary conatins data of abc.txt which is :                                                  good morning\Hi\abc
there\match
bye                                                                                                                         I want to match Hi which is present between two \. The match must be exact.

Comment: @Shivani: I'm afraid it's still not very clear what you're asking. Can you please edit your code to add Data::Dumper's representation of `@ary` (`print Dumper \@ary`) along with the exact output that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't wanting to use only `grep` for some reason, this code works and finds the match between escape characters:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @ary = ("/abc/pqr/pattern/xyz");

if ("@ary" =~ m/(pattern)/) {
print "match is $1";
}
else {
print "no match";
}

exit 0;
```

Comment: But if my @ary = ("/abc/pqr/pattern123/xyz"); it still matches since grep is used. I want to match exact "pattern". So even if pattern123 exists, it says 'no match"

Comment: also, the contents in the file have back slash not forward slash, thus it is not working in my case.

Comment: if (grep m{\\\Q$str\E\\}, @ary ) { ... } this did the trick! Thank you :)